# How to make an edge file based on shared attributes in Gephi

Tags: excel, gephi

I’m new to Gephi and looking for some help with creating some edge files. I have small datasets with much attribute data (which successfully import from .csv format), and I’d like to make various nondirectional edge files based on shared attributes. For example, say I had attribute data for people, noting their state of origin, team preference, and alma mater

Joel    /   WI  /   Packers /   UW

Kate    /   WI  /   Packers /   Marquette

Sara    /   MN  /   Packers /   UW

Slim    /   MN  /   Vikings /   UM

Skip    /   MN  /   Vikings /   Drake

I need to be able to create various edge files defined by the shared attribute, e.g. in one edge file, Joel and Kate share an edge while Sara, Slim, and Skip share edges apart. In reality, my data have many more attributes and far more nodes, so hand-creating the edge file would be laborious. I feel as though Gephi should be able to do this, but I’m entirely failing at figuring out how. In short, I do not need help on importing an edge file, I need help making some.

Comment: So you want let's say to create undirected edges `Joel--UW`, `Sara--UW`, etc. right?

Comment: Indeed, so that if I wanted to make a "alma mater" edge file, Joel and Sara would share an edge (an undirected one). I'm getting the sense that Gephi cannot do this; it seems to assume one comes to the table with premade edge files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way of doing this with Gephi. You could however do this with your favourite spreadsheet software, save one CSV file with your nodes and one with your edges. In your case the files could look like

**Nodes.csv**

```
Id, State, Team
Joel, WI, Packers
Kate, WI, Packers
Sara, MN, Packers
Slim, MN, Vikings
Skip, MN, Vikings
UW
UM
Marquette
Drake
```

**Edges.csv**

```
Source, Target
Joel, UW
Kate, Marquette
Sara, UW
Slim, UM
Skip, Drake
```

Note that I added extra lines at the end of the nodes' file to denote the nodes representing `alma matter`